# The config profile (profile1) could not be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-subsystem-for-linux, aws-cli, windows-terminal

I use aws cli commands from my Windows PC using Windows Terminal and it is working fine. I recently installed WSL to my PC and now when I use an aws cli command like "aws s3 ls --profile profile1" I get the error: "The config profile (profile1) could not be found". I already have the profiles that I am using stored in my .aws/config and can confirm that when I use powershell from my Windows Terminal, it is working fine. Any ideas what might be the issue here?

I already tried doing "aws configure" from my WSL/Ubuntu distro in my Windows Terminal but still not working